# need to find first few characters in a line and add them to the end of the line using regex in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to find first 2 or 3 or 4 characters from start of each line and add them to the end of the line. sample data is as below.

```
--sample data
    ('10','aaaaa','user_abc','user_abc'),   
    ('101','aaaaa','user_abc','user_abc'),  
    ('1001','aaaaa','user_abc','user_abc'),  

---sample data after replace should look as below
    ('10','aaaaa','user_abc','user_abc',10),
    ('101','aaaaa','user_abc','user_abc',101),
    ('1001','aaaaa','user_abc','user_abc',1001),
```

I am able to find first 2,3,4 characters using regex in notepad++

> find what: (('\d{2,4}')
> but not able to append/replace these values correctly at the end of the line.

Comment: this should work: https://regex101.com/r/86G8dT/1

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for the solution, it is working in regex101 but it did not work in notepad++, so I had to use Wiktor's solution. Thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \('(\d+)'(.*?)\)(,?)
Replace: ('$1'$2,$1)$3
```

### Demo

This regex pattern matches:

- `\(` match `(`
- `'(\d+)'` match a string literal which is a number in `$1`
- `(.*?)` then capture the rest of the tuple in `$2`
- `\)` match `)`
- `(,?)` match optional ending comma in `$3`

We then piece together the replacement, adding the number in `$1` as a literal at the end of the tuple.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Thank you for the solution it worked. I had to tweak replace as below \('$1'$2,$1\)$3, otherwise it is removing open and close parenthesis.